# C program for steps and stairs

Tags: c

So I am writing a program where we take input on total number of stairs and number of steps in one go. So for example.

Lets say

```
stairs=10;
steps=3;
```

So starting from zero. It goes. 0-1-2. Then Goes back to 1 and goes 1-2-3, 2-3-4, 3-4-5, 4-5-6 and so on till 8-9-10.
I wrote code for it. But something is missing. Here it is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,stair,step;
    stair=10;
    step=3;

    for(i=0;i<=stair;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=step;j++)
        {
            printf("\nJ:::%d",j);
        }    
       printf("\tI:::%d",i);
    }
}
```

Instead of giving just code. Can someone help me with logic ?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: use `for(j=i;j<i+step;j++)` instead of `for(j=1;j<=step;j++)` as j should start from the value of i and it should run upto current value i.e + number of step. but first for loop you need to run upto `<=stair-step`

Comment: What error/output you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,stair,step;
    stair=10;
    step=3;
    for(i=0;i<=stair-step+1;i++)// here we are decreasing step bcz we are ruuning loop for extra steps in next for loop
    {
        for(j=i;j<i+step;j++)
        {    
            printf("\nJ:::%d",j);    
        }    
        printf("\tI:::%d",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As we now there is pattern.
0-1-2
1-2-3
2-3-4
3-4-5
its a common series 0,1,2,3... in evrey row

As every row starts with +1 of the previous row starts that is value of i.
so we will start `j=i` in every loop as i will run 0,1,2,3...

And next we need to run upto the value of step so we will write `j<i+step`
so that it wiil run upto current value of i + number of steps.
for suppose i=0;
step=3

```
for(j=i;j<i+step;j++)
```

j=0 initial value j<0+3 means loop will run from 0 to 2

```
i=1 =>loop will run from j=1 to j<1+3  Output 1,2,3  
i=2 =>loop will run from j=2 to j<2+3  Output 2,3,4  
i=3 =>loop will run from j=3 to j<3+3  Output 3,4,5
...
..
..
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you actually mean, but if you want to go up the stairs with the number of steps then you need to change the increment value in your for loop:

```
for(j=1;j<=step;j+=step)
```

Comment: Imagine you are exercising. So for every 4 steps you climb say S1 to S4 out of S10 you come back to S1+ 1 i.e S2. And S2 you climb 4 steps. i.e S2 - S3 - S4 -S5 then you come back to S2+1 i.e S3 and climb 4 steps again and so on until you reach S10